# Put UIAlertView above UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: objective-c, view, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to see in a moment my UIAlert above my UIActivityIndicatorView, i have this code:

```
- (void)showWithLabelDeterminate{

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

    // Set determinate mode
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;

    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"Loading";

    // myProgressTask uses the HUD instance to update progress
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myProgressTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}

- (void)myProgressTask
{
    float progress = 0.0f;

    while (progress < 0.99f) 
    {
        progress += 0.01f;
        HUD.progress = progress;
        usleep(50000);

        if(progress > 0.02f & progress < 0.05f)  
        {
            NSString * string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8080/......"];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string]; 

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
                                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

           urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]; 

           if(!urlData) 
           {
                [self simpleAlert];

           }
           else
           {
                   datos = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithData:urlData  encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
           }
       }
    }
}

-(void)simpleAlert 
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Dont connect!!"   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Refresh" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}
```

The problem is that i dont see my UIAlertView above my UIActivityIndicatorView.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myProgressTask` is either executing on a background thread or is blocking the main thread with its calls to `usleep`.

If it's on a background thread then your use of `UIAlertView` is invalid because UIKit is, in the general case, usable from the main thread only. The quickest solution would be to use `performSelectorOnMainThread:...` to call `simpleAlert`.

If it's on the main thread then you're probably blocking UIKit from operating. Obvious comments would follow about using a non-blocking `NSURLConnection` and using `NSTimer` or `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to schedule things to happen after a pause.

Comment: i want to finish my UIActivityIndicatorView because in these moment it  wont be necessary.

Comment: There's no UIActivityIndicatorView in the posted code, presumably it's built in to MBProgressHUD? If I had to guess, I'd say that, of my two guesses, probably you want to change your call to simpleAlert, so as to issue it on the main thread.

Comment: YES, YES, Sorry Tommy, i referred to MBProgressHUD, and yes i want close this progressHUD and init my UIAlertView.

Comment: SOLUTION: [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(simpleAlert) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];